# Inserting a comment string in Z3

Tags: z3

I am not sure, if my question is correct.

When I use Z3, I generate the Z3 constraints using C-API. Due this this facility, it is become extremely easy to generate the constraints automatically by writing a C-program. So when I want to see the constraints I use the C-API `Z3_solver_get_assertions` to generate the constraints in the `smt2` format.

Now, due to automatic generation the lines of constraints vary for me quite a lot. When I want to debug these constraints, I always have to find where exactly a specific constraint is. This is a little tedious task. However, my question is that, can I insert a comment string in the Z3 solver, in between my assertions such that it will print that string when I want to dump the constraints?

so what I would like is something like this -

```
Z3_Comment("Constraints of Type 1");
Z3_solver_assert(..)
..
..
Z3_solver_assert(..)
Z3_solver_assert(..)
Z3_solver_assert(..)
...
Z3_Comment("Constraints of Type 2");
Z3_solver_assert(..)
...
...
Z3_solver_assert(..)
Z3_solver_assert(..)
...
Z3_Comment("Constraints of Type 3");
Z3_solver_assert(..)
```

and when I dump the constraints it should print -

```
;; Constraints of Type 1
assert((..))
..
..
(assert(..))
(assert(..))
(assert(..))
...
;; Constraints of Type 2
(assert(..))
...
...
(assert(..))
(assert(..))
...
;; Constraints of Type 3
(assert(..))
```

Maybe my question is too un-realistic.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z3 API does *not* provide this functionality. I think the easiest solution is to create your own data-structure for storing expressions+comments. You can do it by using a list/array of expression/string.

Comment: the problem was I was running out of memory. however, it is okay. I can live with it. thanks !